# Admin route not showing - LAMP - Laravel - Ubuntu

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu on my home pc. At work I am working on Windows. My application has frontend and backend:

```
http://localhost/mysite/public/
http://localhost/mysite/public/admin/
```

I have installed php, apache, mysql on ubuntu, and my frontend application is running, but when I try to go on admin area, it is showing the file structure:

```
Index of /mysite/public/admin
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -    
[DIR]   css/    2017-02-25 14:03    -    
[DIR]   img/    2017-02-25 13:20    -    
[DIR]   js/ 2017-02-25 14:03    -    
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Then I tried to add Allowoveride All to my apache2.conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

<Directory /var/www/mysite/public/admin>
    Allowoverride All
</Directory>
```

But still, admin route is not showing on Ubuntu, but on Windows does. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to put this in the config:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```